# Custom Paypal form only collecting some data after completed transaction

Tags: forms, paypal

I have created a custom form following information I have gained from the Paypal KB, StackOverflow and other support forums. However things are not working as I had planned. I'm guessing I've missed something along the way that's causing my issue.

I have created a custom donation button building the base of what I need in Paypal, but then not saving the button, and using the code Paypal generates as the base which I then customize (code posted below). The point is to collect info of the type of donation (dropdown), name of the person the donation is honoring (text field), the amount the donation is for (amount field) and then 5 other optional text fields using the on and os variables. At the end of all fields is the Paypal donate button.

**What happens correctly:**

When someone fills out the form and then clicks donate **ALL** values they enter into the form show up properly on the PayPal payment page.

When the transaction is complete the DONOR gets an email showing their transaction AND shows all the information from the form they filled out in the donation details area. Everything on the donor side goes perfectly and they never know there is a problem.

**What goes wrong:**

HOWEVER, things go awry for the organization accepting the donation at payment completion. When the organization gets the email notification of the payment only the top 3 values from the donation form show in the details (value from the dropdown menu, the value in the first text field, and the amount field). All other relevant paypal transaction info is there and the transaction is fine. But all the needed detail that was collected from the custom form is missing. If I log into the paypal account that received the payment I see the transaction, but just as the notification email all data after the amount is missing.

**Summary:**

The custom form, for the donor, appears to function properly including values passed from the web form to the paypal payment form and even included in the donation receipt email received by the donor. However, when it comes to the organization only the first 3 fields show in the notification email and on the transaction itself in the paypal account

Any idea why all values show up on the donor email notification and only 3 values show up on the organization site? Has my formatting of the form (adding spaces between fields) broken the form? If so why does all info show properly for the donor and not the organization? I have included the form code below. Please advise. Thank you so much!

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top"><input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations"> <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@sthecompany.org"> <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"> <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Honor/Memorial Donation"> <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services"> <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0"> <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Please add your comments here"> <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2"> <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"> <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Gift Type">Gift Type</td></tr>
<tr>
<td height="32"><select name="os0">
<option value="Honor">Honor</option>
<option value="Memorial">Memorial</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Name">In Honor or Memory of</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="amount">Amount $<br /></label><input id="amount" type="text" name="amount" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br />If you would like a letter sent to the honoree or next of kin,<br />please fill out the following information otherwise leave blank. <br /><br /> <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Notification Name">Notification Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /><input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Notification Address">Notification Address</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><textarea name="os3" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /><input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Notification City">Notification City</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="os4" maxlength="200"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /><input type="hidden" name="on5" value="Notification State">Notification State</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="os5" maxlength="200"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><br /><input type="hidden" name="on6" value="Notification Zip">Notification Zip</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="os6" maxlength="200"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br /> <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted"> <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1"></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to produce the same results that you describe.  I would suggest opening up a ticket with PayPal's Merchant Technical Team at [www.paypal.com/mts](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  Once you have a ticket opened up, if you would like to provide the ticket number I will grab your ticket and look into this further.  It may be a bug or intended, I would have to look deeper into the code.  Intially some of the additional variables were not supported for some buttons, but I will look into it further and update you through your ticket as to if this is a bug or something that needs to have a feature request filed for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked whether those custom values are sent through an IPN message, but that might solve the problem.